# Reuse Supertest tests on a remote URL

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, supertest

I'm using [MochaJS](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/) and [SuperTest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) to test my API during development and absolutely LOVE it.

However, I would like to also turn these same tests to remotely tests my staging server before pushing the code out to production.

### Is there a way to supply request with a remote URL or proxy to a remote URL?

Here is a sample of a test I use

```
        request(app)
        .get('/api/photo/' + photo._id)
        .set(apiKeyName, apiKey)
        .end(function(err, res) {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (res.body._id !== photo._id) throw Error('No _id found');
            done();
        });
```

Comment: Great question!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You already mentioned it, since you are targeting remote URL just replace the app with your remote server URL

```
request('http://yourserverhere.com')
.get('/api/photo/' + photo._id)
.set(apiKeyName, apiKey)
.end(function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (res.body._id !== photo._id) throw Error('No _id found');
    done();
});
```

Comment: This is now the most correct answer to the question. Simply adding the URL to the `supertest` constructor is sufficient to point tests toward that URL.

Comment: Yep, works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 33):

I'm not sure if you can do it with supertest. You can definitely do it with [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent). Supertest is built on superagent. An example would be:

```
var request = require('superagent');
var should = require('should');

var agent = request.agent();
var host = 'http://www.yourdomain.com'

describe('GET /', function() {
  it('should render the index page', function(done) {
    agent
      .get(host + '/')
      .end(function(err, res) {
        should.not.exist(err);
        res.should.have.status(200);
        done();
      })
  })
})
```

So you cannot directly use your existing tests. But they are very similiar. And if you add

```
var app = require('../app.js');
```

to the top of your tests you easily switch between testing your local app and the deployment on a remote server by changing the `host` variable

```
var host = 'http://localhost:3000';
```

Edit:

Just found an example for supertest in the [docs#example](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest#example)

```
request = request.bind(request, 'http://localhost:5555');  // add your url here

request.get('/').expect(200, function(err){
  console.log(err);
});

request.get('/').expect('heya', function(err){
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: I think you're on to something. Let me do some testing and if it works out, I'll accept. Thanks.

Comment: I assume this has changed since this question was last answered, but you can simply use the `supertest` constructor with the absolute url / prefix:

`request = supertest('http://localhost:8080/api'); request.get(...`

Answer (score 3):

Other answers din't work for me.

They use `.end(function(err, res) {` which is a problem for any async http calls, need to use `.then` instead:

A sample working code is below:

> File: \test\rest.test.js

```
let request = require("supertest");
var assert = require("assert");

describe("Run tests", () => {
  request = request("http://localhost:3001");        // line must be here, change URL to yours

  it("get", async () => {

    request
      .get("/")                                      // update path to yours
      .expect(200)
      .then((response) => {                          // must be .then, not .end
        assert(response.body.data !== undefined);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        assert(err === undefined);
      });

  });

});
```

> File: \package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
  "supertest": "^6.1.3",
  "mocha": "^8.3.0",
},
"scripts": {
  "test": "mocha"
}
```

> Install & run

```
npm i
npm test
```